# Why do I need 'default' in module export?

Tags: webpack, module

I am exporting some modules with ES6 syntax and bundling them with webpack.
But this only works when I include the `default` keyword. What does this do?

Why can't I just use `export class Person` ? Webpack complains that it needs the `default` class.

```
export class Person       // doesn't work
export default class {    // works
    constructor (id) {
        this.name = id
    }
    logname () {
        console.log("Person: " + this.name)
    }
}
```

app

```
import Person from "./person.js";

export class App {
    constructor () {
        const p = new Person("Slim Willy Joe")
        p.logname()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this

```
export class Example
```

Then your import should looks like this

```
import { Example } from 'your-file';
```

If you want to rename your class (Example -> MyClass), you need

```
import { Example as MyClass } from 'your-file'
```

But if you are using default your code will look like this

```
// example.js
export default class Example

// your-another-file
import MyClass from 'example';
```

Sometimes we need naming export and default is not a good solution

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed those `{ ... }`.